# GroupBy and Aggregate Function In JAVA spark Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to do below operation on a dataset for Grouping and aggregating the Column expend to add up. But this isn't working on a normal Dataset it says for  RelationalGroupedDataset. How can I achieve the below operation in the Normal Dataset

```
dataset.select.(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("expend")).groupBy(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("expend")).agg(sum("expend"))
```

The SQL query looks like 
`select col1,col2,SUM(expend) from table group by col1,col2`

The Columns gets repeated when I try this code. 
`dataset.columns()` gives me `[col1,col2,expend,expend]`  is the way of approach right?

Comment: can you provide the error message ?

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I get the duplicate cols Shankar

Comment: @ShankarKoirala anything u wana add-up here ?

Comment: are you trying to groupBy `col1 and col2` and sum the `expend`??

Comment: yes @ShankarKoirala Suppose I have a data for two rows as `(item1,item2,4,4)` & `(item1,item2,5,5)` I want it to be grouped as `(item1,item2,9,9)` this is what I want the result to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used below code to solve the issue.
Created a list `List<Column> aggCols;`
This will have the operation of the columns.
here I added as

```
aggCols.add(expr("sum(expend1)"));
addCols.add(expr("sum(expend2)"));

 dataset.select.(col("col1"),col("col2"),col("expend"))
.groupBy(col("col1"),col("col2"))
.agg(aggCols.get(0), JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(aggCols.subList(1,aggCols.size()).iterator()).asScala().toSeq());
```

I added some checks when I have only one col to sum then I directly do the sum.

Comment: any advice how to handle this UDF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas